# storing anonymous information in a database

Tags: database, security

Our application will store some information from a user that we do not want to be traced back to any other records in the database.  For example (albeit a stupid one) - a user must pay to tell us anonymously what their favorite color is.  We want to store each color record as a new row in the database and keep track of the transaction information.

If we stored the colors and transactions in separate tables, the rows could be correlated to one another if the server were hacked, by using the sequential ID of the rows (because a color will always have a transaction) or by the creation time of the row.  So to solve this we won't have a sequential ID column for the colors table, or an update/modification time for the colors table.

Now, the only way to associate a color with a transaction is to look at the files that are used to actually store the database information.  While this may be difficult and tedious, I imagine it is still possible because the colors table information would probably be stored sequentially in the files.

**How can I store database information in an un-ordered matter, so that this could never happen?**  I suppose a more general question is how do I store information anonymously and securely? (But that is way too broad)

Obviously, an answer is don't let your database get hacked, but not a good one.

Comment: Is that an accurate assumption that the data would be stored sequentially?

Comment: Um, how are YOU going to correlate between the two tables if nobody else can?

Comment: @Joe - I'm not sure, but I wouldn't want to leave it to chance. We are using postgres, but if there is some known way to store randomly, I'd welcome using it too.

Comment: @Madbreaks - we don't need to, but we want to be able to analyze the anonymous data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-generate millions of rows and randomly populate them.

Comment: Perhaps by running a SHA1 + salt of the current time modded by the number of rows, with collisions handled by searching sequentially from there for the next opening.

Comment: Correct.  The scheme would be analogous to how a hashmap inserts entries.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to analyze data, you will need to understand it, and if you can attacker can also. No matter what clever solution you will come up with correletion will still be possible. Relational DB transaction logs, wil show what and when and where was inserted updated deleted. So you cannot provide 100% decoupling of data, if you want to use the same db. You could encrypt data with some HSM, which would render stolen data useless for attacker. Or you can store data on some other machine with random delay or some batch processing, (wait and insert 20 records instead of one)... but it can be tricky and it can fail.

Comment: I'm not worried about the data being understood, rather associated with other records in the database.  I won't need this association either, so I am trying to remove all ways that this can occur.  DB logs can be filtered and/or turned off, so I'm not too worried about those.

Answer (score 0):

Consider leveraging a non-realtional database, e.g. [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).